# Extrusion is extruding in large increments

Tags: modeling

My problem is that I am working on a project, but when I extrude in it it extrudes in large increments instead of extruding smoothly.Why is this so? In my other projects the extrusion works just fine.

Comment: do you have the snap function on?

Comment: No I don't think so I can check and get back to you but thank you for answering